# How can I put values in the bars of a lattice barchart and have a legend

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend, lattice, stacked-chart

UPDATED

If I remove the "points=FALSE" from the auto-key line, the legend will show the colors, but will not show it has a rectangle, but as a circle/point.

ORIGINAL QUESTION

I have a stacked barchart that includes a legend and I want to add figures within the bars to show the relative value.  I seem to be able to either (legend and values), but not both.

Using this test code below, I get a graph that shows the values within the stacked barchart.

```
dta <- data.frame(x=c(46.0, 14.7, 16.4, 15.8, 7.0), y=c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth"))
barchart(data=dta, ~x, group=y,
         stack=T,col=sort(brewer.pal(7,"Purples")), xlab="Percent",
         box.width=.5, scales=list(tick.number=10),
         panel=function(x,y,...){
           panel.barchart(x,y,...)
           panel.text(cumsum(x)-dta$x/2,y,labels=dta$x)
         })
```

If I run this code, I get a graph with a legend.

```
dta <- data.frame(x=c(46.0, 14.7, 16.4, 15.8, 7.0), y=c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth"))
barchart(data=dta, ~x, group=y,
         stack=T, xlab="Percent",
         box.width=.5, scales=list(tick.number=10),
         auto.key = list(space="right", cex=.5, border=T, points=F, lines=F, lwd=5, text=c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")),
         par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col = rainbow(length(c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")))), 
               fill=rainbow(length(c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")))))
```

But when I combine the code, so that it looks like this, the resulting graph does not show the colors in the legend:

```
dta <- data.frame(x=c(46.0, 14.7, 16.4, 15.8, 7.0), y=c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth"))
barchart(data=dta, ~x, group=y,
         stack=T, xlab="Percent",
         box.width=.5, scales=list(tick.number=10),
         auto.key = list(space="right", cex=.5, border=T, points=F, lines=F, lwd=5, text=c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")),
         par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col = rainbow(length(c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")))), 
                             fill=rainbow(length(c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")))),
         panel=function(x,y,...){
           panel.barchart(x,y,...)
           panel.text(cumsum(x)-dta$x/2,y,labels=dta$x)
         })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the code to add "rectangles=T" to the auto-key line works.  It now shows both the values within the bar and the legend with the colors  The code looks like this:

```
dta <- data.frame(x=c(46.0, 14.7, 16.4, 15.8, 7.0), y=c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth"))
barchart(data=dta, ~x, group=y,
         stack=T, xlab="Percent",
         box.width=.5, scales=list(tick.number=10),
         auto.key = list(space="right", cex=.5, border=T, points=F, rectangles = T, lines=F, lwd=5, text=c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")),
         par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col = rainbow(length(c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")))), 
                             fill=rainbow(length(c("Back", "Neck", "Extrem", "MuscSkel", "Oth")))),
         panel=function(x,y,...){
           panel.barchart(x,y,...)
           panel.text(cumsum(x)-dta$x/2,y,labels=dta$x)
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention this alternative (as you look to have solve your issue by yourself ;) ), you can get the same graph using `ggplot2`, you just need to use `dplyr` to create a new column `w`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
dta %>% mutate(w = cumsum(x)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(xmin = w-x, xmax = w, ymin = 1, ymax = 3))+
  geom_rect( aes(fill = y))+
  geom_text(aes(label = x, x = w - x/2, y = 2))+
  ylim(0,4)+
  xlab("Percent")+
  ylab("")+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]